# using php 'if - clause' in form attribute inside a php function

Tags: php, html, forms, function, attributes

Im building a simple element to show search results. I'm using a php function, so I can while-loop the results and display them.

The function is named search_results and looks like this:

```
<?php
function search_results($u_country, $user_name, $business_user, $brand_name, $product_name, $up_condition, $up_commentary, $up_price, $up_shipping, $up_amount, $up_id)  {
    $element    =   "
            <div>
                <form action='search.php' method='post'>
                    <div class='search_body'>
                         <span class='country'>$u_country</span>
                         <span class='username'>$user_name</span>
                         <span class='business_user'>$business_user</span>
                         <span class='product_name'>$product_name</span>
                         <span class='up_condition'>$up_condition</span>
                         <span class='commentary'>$up_commentary</span>
                         <span class='price'>$up_price</span>
                         <span class='amount'>$up_amount</span>
                         <span>
                            <input type='number' name='up_amount' min='1' max='$up_amount' placeholder='1'>
                         </span>
                         <span>
                            <input type='hidden' name='product_id' value='$up_id'>
                         </span>
                         <span>
                            <button type='submit' name='add_cart' disabled='".if(!isset($_SESSION['username']))."'>Warenkorb</button>
                         </span>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
    ";
    echo $element;
};
```

But I want to implement some php in some of the attributes. For example I want to disable the "add_cart" button if the user is not logged in. But if i use some php inside the html form it always crushes.

if I put the form in single quotes and every attribute in double quotes it won't translate the variables.

my understanding is that i have to end a html string with " and use a . to separate it from the php part, but I can't make it work.

Is there something I'm missing? is it not possible to mix in php into a html form while inside a function?

couldn't find a solution for this and looked through the other threads but couldn't find anything relative.

Sorry if this is a dumb question I'm still learning to code.

if I put the form in single quotes and every attribute in double quotes it won't translate the variables.

I want to further use php inside the attributes of the form to make the results more interactive. For example i want the displayed name of the product to be a link to the product page so it will need to use a variable for that.

Comment: Break you code up into bits that do works and use `$element .= ....` to concatenate the working bits into the variable

Comment: could you elaborate what you mean by working bits? do I still use double quotes after the = to frame the form?

Answer (score 0):

Break you code up into bits that do works and use $element .= .... to concatenate the working bits into the variable

For example

```
function search_results($u_country, $user_name, $business_user, $brand_name, 
                        $product_name, $up_condition, $up_commentary, $up_price, 
                        $up_shipping, $up_amount, $up_id)  
{
    $element    = "<div>
                    <form action='search.php' method='post'>
                        <div class='search_body'>";
    $element .= "<span class='country'>$u_country</span>
                <span class='username'>$user_name</span>
                <span class='business_user'>$business_user</span>
                <span class='product_name'>$product_name</span>
                <span class='up_condition'>$up_condition</span>
                <span class='commentary'>$up_commentary</span>
                <span class='price'>$up_price</span>
                <span class='amount'>$up_amount</span>
                <span>
                    <input type='number' name='up_amount' min='1' max='$up_amount' placeholder='1'>
                </span>
                <span>
                    <input type='hidden' name='product_id' value='$up_id'>
                </span>
                <span>";

    $t = '';    // default to not disabled
    if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])){
        $t = " disabled='disabled' ";
    }
    $element .= "<button type='submit' name='add_cart' $t>Warenkorb</button>
                </span>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>";

    echo $element;
}
```

Comment: oh that seems smart. I will try this out, thank you very much for your time

Answer (score 0):

**step 1**: run the code (the button will be disabled)
**step 2** refresh the page then the button is not anymore disabled(f5 key,..)
**step 3** delete cookies so the button will be disabled again and proceed with the step 2

this is an "environment" to prove you the function can work.
if you really need `echo $element;` part then drop the return ... and replace it ..

**good luck**

```
<?php
    
    
    
    function search_results($u_country, $user_name, $business_user, $brand_name, $product_name, $up_condition, $up_commentary, $up_price, $up_shipping, $up_amount, $up_id,$onoff)  {
        $onoffanswer=($onoff?'disabled':'');
    return <<<stuff
    <div>
    <form action='search.php' method='post'>
        <div class='search_body'>
             <span class='country'>$u_country</span>
             <span class='username'>$user_name</span>
             <span class='business_user'>$business_user</span>
             <span class='product_name'>$product_name</span>
             <span class='up_condition'>$up_condition</span>
             <span class='commentary'>$up_commentary</span>
             <span class='price'>$up_price</span>
             <span class='amount'>$up_amount</span>
             <span>
                <input type='number' name='up_amount' min='1' max='$up_amount' placeholder='1'>
             </span>
             <span>
                <input type='hidden' name='product_id' value='$up_id'>
             </span>
             <span>
                <button type='submit' name='add_cart' {$onoffanswer}>Warenkorb</button>
             </span>
        </div>
    </form>
    </div>
    
    stuff;
    
    };
    
    
    
    session_start();
    
    echo search_results(
    'country'
    ,'username'
    ,'businessuser'
    ,'brandname'
    ,'productname'
    ,'upcondition'
    ,'commentary'
    ,'upprice'
    ,'upshipping'
    ,'upamount'
    ,'1111'
    ,!isset($_SESSION['username'])
    );
    print_r ($_SESSION);//phpinfo();
    $_SESSION['username']='eeee';
    ?>
```